# resolving string (read from database) to list python

Tags: database, string, list, python-2.7

I have a list stored in database as varchar. When  I read the list value, it is read as string. I'm trying to convert string to a valid list
Here are 2 example lists  I have

```
str_db_bins = [10,20,30,40] (This is string)
The desired output is 
str_db_bins_list = [10,20,30,40] (This is list)
```

I want to convert this to list. When I use split method I get [[,1,0...]] which is not the desired output

2nd situtation is

```
str_db_lov = ['id','num','val']. 
When I use split method, again I get weird output
The desired output is to read this as list
str_db_lov_list = ['id', 'num', 'val']
```

How do I deal with these situations
Thanks
Pari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str_db_bins_list = eval(str_db_bins)
str_db_lov_list  = eval(str_db_lov)
```